# Isomorphism preserving transformation graph to graph of logarithmic boolean width and bounded degeneracy

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, isomorphism-testing

The [paper On graph classes with logarithmic boolean-width](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.0216)
claims that some graph problems are fixed parameter tractable with parameter
the boolean width.

In particular, boolean-width of the complement of $k$-degenerate graph
is at most $k\log(n)$.

We got isomorphism preserving transformation
graph $G$ to graph $G_m$ of logarithmic boolean width:  set $G'_m$ to be the $m$-subdivision
(i.e. subdivide each edge $m$ times) and set $G_m$ the complement
of $G'_m$.  $G'_m$ is $2$-degenerate.

$G_m$ is of logarithmic boolean width since its
order is $O(m n^2)$ and its complement is $2$-degenerate.

For odd $m$, $G_m$ can be partitioned in two cliques (it is co-bipartite).

1. What is the intuition about so low boolean width for all transformed graphs?
2. Are there islands of tractable problems on $G_m$ related to problems on $G$?
3. Are there graph classes for which the transformation gives bounded
   boolean width?